# How do I rewrite a subdomain to use a prettier format in a wordpress environment?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web-hosting

#### How do I rewrite:

subdomain.example.com/page to example.com/subdomain/page?

I've tried redirecting in my cPanel and changing the site URL in wp_options. Still no luck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following htaccess code for this purpose.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No luck. It redirects me to the main URL...Any other options?
How should my site URL in the WP_options table look before adding this to the htaccess? subdomain.example.com or example.com/subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/%1/$1" [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```